# Problem using Matcher and Pattern objects in Java

Tags: java, regex, posix

I am trying to make a Lexer.  I am using a Matcher object to get the next token from an HTML String.  I am trying to use the lookingAt() method of the Matcher to get the first occurance of the POSIX expression I am looking for.  The problem is group() is supposed to print out only that phrase that matches the expression but instead it prints out the whole HTML String.  Here is the code:

```
public static final String[] DEFAULT_RULES = new String[] {         
            // PUT YOUR REGULAR EXPRESSIONS HERE.  SEE THE ORDER BELOW
            "<!--.*-->",                                    // A comment TESTED
            "<\\p{Alnum}+.*\\p{Blank}*/>",                  // Singular Tag
            "<\\p{Alnum}+.*[^/]*>",                         // Opening Tag TESTED
            "</\\p{Alnum}+\\p{Space}*>",                    // Closing Tag TESTED
            "&.*;",                                         // HTTP Entity TESTED
            ".*"    };
```

METHOD:

```
    for( int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_RULES.length; i++ ) {// Loop through each expression and try to find a matching phrase
        pattern = Pattern.compile( DEFAULT_RULES[i], Pattern.DOTALL );  // Get a Regex Pattern
        matcher = pattern.matcher( mainString );    // Check if Pattern matches the String

        //matcher.region( position, mainString.length() );  // Make the Region start from the current pointer to the end

        if( matcher.lookingAt() ) {     // Match found at current position
            int s = matcher.start();
            int e = matcher.end();
            String nextToken = matcher.group();     // Save the current phrase that matched the expression
            position = matcher.end();           // Move position pointer to the character after the end of the Token
            return nextToken;// return the Token
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** DEFAULT_RULES is a list of expression strings that I am looking for.  The ouput I am expecting is:

```
<P>
```

but instead I get the whole HTML file.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you show your regex?

Comment: Have you thought of using a StreamTokenizer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lookingAt()` applies the regex as if it were anchored at the beginning with `\A`, so the only match you'll ever get is one that starts at the very beginning of the subject.  If the subject doesn't start with, `<` or `&`, the only *regex* in that list that's ever going to match is the last one, `.*`.  And, since you're doing the match in DOTALL mode, the `.*` will always match the entire subject.

It looks like you intended to update the match-start position after each match, and I see you're *saving* the new position, but you never do anything with it.  You need to use it in the `region(int, int)` method to change what the Matcher thinks of as the beginning of the subject, like so:

```
position = matcher.end();
matcher.region(position, matcher.regionEnd());
```

But you're still going to get a lot more than you want with each match because of the `.*` in most of your regexes, all of which are being applied in DOTALL mode.  You need to be much more specific than that.  *How* specific depends on what your ultimate goal is.  If you're trying to write a lexer for a complete, industrial-strength HTML parser, you should drop this right now and read up on how *real* parsers are written.

[Here's](http://regex.info/listing.cgi?ed=3&p=399) a code listing from [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/regex3/index.html) that's similar to what you're doing.  It demonstrates some important techniques like saving the regexes as compiled Pattern objects, and swapping them out using Matcher's `usePattern()` method instead of constantly creating new Pattern and Matcher objects.  (He also adds `\\G` to each regex and uses `find()` or `find(int)` to apply them; that part's outdated.  `region()` and `lookingAt()` are all you need.)

Answer (score 1):

Group index 0 is always the whole matching string. Index 1+ returns the individual groups. So

String: abc

Regex: .*(b).*

Group 0: abc

Group 1: b

Comment: I tried 1 but it gives me an Out of Bound error.  Also matcher.end() returns 1150 instead of 3 which is the length of the <P> tag. I've also tried just using group() but that also returns the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is likely to be matching the whole document and not just the `<P>` tag. This may be due to greedy matching. If you're using something like this:

```
<P.*>
```

you're probably better off modifying it along the lines of

```
<P.*?>
```

or

```
<P[^>]*>
```

See section "Reluctant quantifiers" on this page: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Yea that was the problem.  Well since we're here how do I say ANY character ANY number of times except '<' and '&'?  I tried [^<^&]* but that doesn't work.

Comment: @FreeLance: In that case, would you mind marking the answer as correct? Thanks.

Comment: @FreeLance: Try [^<&]* -- Character classes match any one of the characters between the brackets. If you want to negate the class, i.e.., match any character *except* the ones in brackets, add a single ^ as the first character after the opening bracket.